# Package with configured table and columns

Tags: business-intelligence, ssis

i need to create a package to pull data from source to destination. I know this is a simple package. but here I want the source and destination to be configurable with table and columns. ie the Source or destination table/columns can change. In between there can be transformations. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible if the column counts and types are consistent. A Data Flow works by knowing ahead of time what the data should look like. It does not support dynamically changing the types or the number of columns.